# How to instantiate a SaveFileDialog in a web application

Tags: asp.net, file, upload, savefiledialog

I am new to Visual Studio and ASP. I have a web application in which I need to use SaveFileDialog. When I open the Dialogs group in the toolbox, all the controls including SaveFileDialog are greyed out. Is there an alternative method? I notice that in the Standard group there is a FileUpload control but it is not matched by an equivalent FileSave or FileDownload.

Answer (score 0):

The FileSaveDialog is a windows UI control that can be used when developing native Windows applications. They are not possible to use in web projects that are run in any browser on any device.

To save a file from the web browser you can use JavaScript as described in [Javascript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file).